# Active/Passive to Active/Active

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustering

In layman terms, what does it mean to have "Active/Active"?  What are the steps to achieve this configuration?

Edit:
We currently have an "Active/Passive" setup which isn't efficiently making use of the hardware so we need a "Active/Active" configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Active/Active could mean two things (or maybe others depending on the project manager's imagination).

1. At least two clustered instances of SQL Server on two nodes of a Windows cluster. This allows both pieces of hardware to be used simultaneously and not wasted, one server for each instance, with the worst case scenario being one server fails and the other takes all of the load for both instances in that case.
2. More likely, a manager thinks that both nodes of a cluster could be actively running the same instance of SQL Server, with reads and writes going to both. This is not how clustering works; it is not for scale out but for high availability / disaster recovery. But it is a common misconception, especially for managers. :-)

Most people that work with clustering regularly cringe when they hear active / active. It's inaccurate, ambiguous, and to them it's like nails on a chalkboard.

Comment: Thx Aaron. What are the various (read: easiest to the toughest :) ) ways by which we can achieve this?

Comment: To achieve *what*? You need to determine what exactly your manager expects you to achieve before anyone can tell you how to achieve it. Do you have multiple instances of SQL Server on your cluster?

Comment: I am trying to understand generally what are all the different ways by which we can change Active/Passive into Active/Active. In this project we have 2 servers. Server1 has one instance (which is active) and Server2 has one instance (which is passive).

Comment: What does "Active/Active" mean to *you*? What does "one instance (which is passive)" mean?

Comment: "Multi-Instance Failover Cluster"

Comment: @prasanth As Aaron noted, most likely you're looking for #2. As an inheritor of two, two-node multi-instance failover clusters, I can say that it's a real pain. You have a node with with one SQL instance, and another node with another SQL instance. Each instance writes to its own set of disks (LUNs on a SAN). When a failure is initiated (intentionally or otherwise), the "other" instance is (usually) rolled onto the same hardware as the "first" instance. Neat for maintenance, but that physical hardware begins to immediately experience resource pressure.

Comment: Currently i understand that all load goes to Server1 and during its failure Server2 takes over. I am "assuming" that is the reason Server2 is called as passive.

Comment: Also as @AaronBertrand mentioned, it is *not* scaling out, but a means of keeping both SQL instances up in the event of "disaster" on one of the nodes.

Comment: Ok so I think there are several levels of misunderstanding here...

Comment: @prasanth outside of "this is inefficient," is there a compelling business reason to do this? is server 1 under such resource pressure that your boss believes you need to re-architect your application infrastructure such that it takes advantage of another sql server instance on re-purposed hardware? if this is the case, then it'd probably be better to start with tuning the stuff on server 1, rather than throwing more hardware at the situation.

Comment: @swasheck I think it's about wasted hardware. I think the manager thinks that "converting" the cluster to active/active will allow a single instance to utilize both servers simultaneously (which really is a common misconception I encounter a lot). And I think the concepts here like "Active" and "Passive" are grossly misunderstood. I shouldn't have to say "think" so many times in a comment...

Comment: I am sorry for not able to explain the problem properly. All i am trying to understand is the various ways one could achieve the option 1 which you have explained in your answer.

Comment: @swasheck - still i am not getting what re-architect one needs to do? If one says that hardware is being used inefficiently then i would believe that required hardware is already in place.

Comment: @prasanth but do you actually have two installed instances of SQL Server? I do not believe that is what I understood from your comments. You said Server2 has an instance that is passive but I think you meant that Server2 is the passive node in the existing cluster, since SQL Server won't be running there at all until there is a failover. Do you understand the difference between a cluster, a node, and an instance?

Comment: as @AaronBertrand noted, active/active **does not** mean that one instance can leverage double hardware. if you're trying to shed load on the "active" node (the one with the extant sql server instance) by putting another sql instance on the other node, it's going to have a different name. you will then need to migrate the databases on the extant instance to the new instance. *then* you'll need to refactor your code such that it connects to this new instance.